# ModelState.Clear is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a simple contact form built in MVC that uses the Html helper class to generate the textbox and drop down. I'd like to clear the values of the textboxes and drop down list to as it was when the page was rendered using a get (only after the inquiry was submitted properly).

I am using the method `ModelState.Clear()` to perform this clean up but my form values still remain, any idea on what I am doing wrong here? Upon success it does display the message in the code. Below you will find a copy of the code from my controller.

Thanks for taking the time!

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contact(ContactUsViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       bool isSuccess = _siteService.CreateInquiry(model.Inquiry);

       if (isSuccess)
       {
           model.SuccessMessage = "Thank you for contacting us.";
           ModelState.Clear();
       }
    }

    model.InquiryTypes = InquiryTypes;
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In case of success simply redirect to your GET action following the [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern:

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    var model = new ContactUsViewModel
    {
        SuccessMessage = TempData["SuccessMessage"] as string
    };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contact(ContactUsViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       bool isSuccess = _siteService.CreateInquiry(model.Inquiry);
       if (isSuccess)
       {
           TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Thank you for contacting us.";
           return RedirectToAction("Contact");
       }
    }

    // since you are modifying the value of the InquiryTypes property
    // you need to remove it from the modelstate to avoid getting the 
    // old value rendered by the helpers
    ModelState.Remove("InquiryTypes");
    model.InquiryTypes = InquiryTypes;
    return View(model);
}
```

or since I am not a big fan of TempData (because it uses Session and personally I always disable it in my applications), you could simply pass a query string parameter to the Contact GET action like (`success=1`) and inside this action prepare the success message.

Comment: What if we have to return the whole model ?

Comment: Where is ModelState.Clear()?

Answer (score 1):

You should construct a new model object beside invoking  ModelState.Clear(), such as in

```
model = new Vacancies(); 

ModelState.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `ModelState` is a property of a `Controller`, it is not what is holding your submitted form values.  Here's what you'd want to do:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
   bool isSuccess = _siteService.CreateInquiry(model.Inquiry);

   if (isSuccess)
   {
       model = new ContactUsViewModel();  // modified line
       model.SuccessMessage = "Thank you for contacting us.";
   }
}

model.InquiryTypes = InquiryTypes;
return View(model);
```

The [`Controller.ModelState` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.modelstate.aspx), as explained by MSDN:

> Gets the model state dictionary object that contains the **state** of the model and of model-binding **validation**.

All I did in my code example was take out your `ModelState.Clear()` method call and put in `model = new ContactUsViewMode();`.  That's a haphazard way of clearing your ViewModel data properties.

---

#### Alternative Process

You could also do something like this, and change your ViewModel:

```
public class ContactUsViewModel()
{
    // ... all of your existing view model members

    public void Clear()
    {
        this.SomeStringProperty = string.Empty;
        this.SomeIntProperty = 0;
        // ... so on and so forth
    }
}
```

And then instead of creating a new instance of your ViewModel class, you can merely call `Clear()` on your existing instance:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
   bool isSuccess = _siteService.CreateInquiry(model.Inquiry);

   if (isSuccess)
   {
       model.Clear();  // modified line
       model.SuccessMessage = "Thank you for contacting us.";
   }
}

model.InquiryTypes = InquiryTypes;
return View(model);
```

Comment: Actually, your answer is misleading. ModelState IS what holds model values, and is FIRST in priority order of model value providers. I'm pretty sure your second (apternative process) will not work, as you do not clear model state

Comment: @archil Right, but I think the OP is concerned with the form values that are passed back to the view.

Comment: Interesting. I thought about these ideas as well but I thought there would be a cleaner way to accomplish this at the framework level. I did some research it seems the Clear method is used to remove error model errors and not actually reset the model state.

Comment: the form is rebound by the values in the model being passed back to the form, not by ModelState

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late in the game but I came up with the following method `ClearModelState`:

```
public void ClearModelState()
{
    var modelStateKeys = ModelState.Keys;
    var formKeys = Request.Form.Keys.Cast<string>();
    var allKeys = modelStateKeys.Concat(formKeys).ToList();

    var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;

    foreach (var key in allKeys)
    {
        ModelState[key] = new ModelState { Value = new ValueProviderResult(null, null, culture) };
    }
}
```